# How to force CURL to use IP customer send request?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

page1.php

```
<?php
$myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = ".../page2.php";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resultip = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo "My IP: ".$myip."<br>IP CURL use: ".$resultip;
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

result:

My IP: **14.185.13.158**

IP CURL use: **198.143.134.70**

How can I get my own IP *(using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])*, not IP of CURL?

Comment: You'd have to pass it as a GET param or custom header since REMOTE_ADDR will be the IP of the client (or proxy, or other, but let's ignore that). I do have to wonder though why you're trying to curl a local PHP file instead of just including it.

Comment: Hi Jon,
I am testing, that CURL will not be able to use my IP address to execute the query.
But I really want CURL to use my IP address.
I tried the header, but it did not work for REMOTE_ADDR